# How can I transfer my programs on smartphone?

Tags: android, testing, usb, device

I've written a program which uses the accelerometer, but I cannot emulate this sensor on the emulator so I want to install the app on my device.

The problem is, when I connect my phone (LG gt540) to my computer through the USB cable, the device is not recognized.

I should point out, that my phone has no SIM card installed. Is it possible to test my programs on such device? What do I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

I tried on some devices without sim card but they didn't even use a sim card because they were tablets. If you start your phone does the OS start? if so you can maybe conect to wifi and send yourself an email with the apk of your app. You will have to open the email and install the app (you will have to accept some settings for "accept apps from unknown sources".

Answer (score 0):

I don't think not having a SIM card should stop you from running your app on the phone.

Try getting the drivers for your phone. After you install the drivers, Eclipse should automatically detect your device.

Another option is that you can upload the APK somewhere and download it to your phone.

Also make sure the debugging mode is turned ON on your phone before trying to run your app on the phone.